# how to connect to linux server from azure cloud and upload to BLOB storage?

Tags: linux, azure, server, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a 1tb file to azure blob storage. but the file is on a Linux server. Is there anyway I can directly connect and upload this?

1. how do I connect to a Linux server and upload to the BLOB without using ADF? Is there any other way? Can this be done with AZ copy utility tool?
2. is there any faster approach to just uploading to the blob? Usually I upload it from local drives, but now I want to connect to a Linux server

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the Blob Storage as a drive on your Linux server using [`Blobfuse`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse) which is a virtual file system driver for Azure Blob storage. Blobfuse allows you to access your existing block blob data in your storage account through the Linux file system. Blobfuse uses the virtual directory scheme with the forward-slash '/' as a delimiter.

You can read more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux.

Alternately you can also use [`AzCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), [`Azure CLI tools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) and even cross-platform [`Azure PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.6.1) to upload the data.

Comment: I dont have a VM to connect to the linux server. and i am not allowed to install anything on the server. whatever it is i need to connect to the server and copy to blob or adls.